# Heroku doesn't collect static on Django but tell that it does

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

Command `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` returns me something like

```
163 static files copied to '/app/live-static-files/static-root', 
509 post-processed.
```

Here are my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # White Noise
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static-files", "static-root")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static-files", "media-root")
```

`DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 0`

Through `heroku run bash` i go `/app/live-static-files/static-root` and see it's empty (the folder exists as it's in repo with .gitkeep) and server gives 500 error on all requests.

Now with `heroku run bash` i try `python manage.py collectstatic` and it works! But after `heroku restart` it's empty again.

Why Heroku tell that it copied statics, even tell the right path of the statics folder but in fact doesn't do that? Why it actually doesn't do that?

Comment: You can't run `collectstatic` via `heroku run`. Such commands run in one-off dynos that are discarded as soon as the command ends. Make sure to run it as part of your build process ([this is the default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds)) or store your static assets in a shared location, e.g. on Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: @Chris i have `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 0` in configs, anyway it doesn't work and static folder is empty after deploy

Comment: That doesn't belong in your settings file, it's a _Heroku config var_. Clear it with `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`.

Comment: @Chris yes i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".

Take a read of these articles:

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: Yes i know it, but anyway with `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 0` Heroku should each time copy static to `STATIC_ROOT` but now everytime i restart it or make new deploy the `STATIC_ROOT` is empty

Comment: Does your repository contains STATIC_ROOT directory?

Comment: Ah, you are using WhiteNoise, right? Did you add these lines to wsgi.py file also?
`from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise`
`application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)`

Comment: DjangoWhiteNoise looks like deprecated now