# How to setup wsgi.py file in Django for WhiteNoise 5.1.0?

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

I use Heroku and i have a problem with static files - they are creating in `STATIC_ROOT`. I've got that i need to setup `wsgi.py` file for WhiteNoise. I tried some different ways which i found to setup it but i every time get fail. Here is my code:

**/wsgi.py**

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application, root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api_obs.settings')
```

With this here is the last error message in errors thread:

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.'
```

What the right way to setup it? My `settings.py` file is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238587/heroku-doesnt-collect-static-on-django-but-tell-that-it-does) is my previous question with them. I only haven't declared `STATICFILES_DIRS` but it's not required right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit `wsgi.py`, that hasn't been supported since WhiteNoise 4.0 which was released two years ago.

You just need to edit your `MIDDLEWARE` setting, see:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html#quickstart-for-django-apps

Comment: Ok, that's clean. But my problem about not created Heroku static files is stay here..